# regex problem C#

Tags: c#, regex

```
 const string strRegex = @"(?<city_country>.+) ?(bis|zu)? (?<price>[\d.,]+) eur";
            searchQuery = RemoveSpacesFromString(searchQuery);
            Regex regex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match m = regex.Match(searchQuery);
            ComplexAdvertismentsQuery query = new ComplexAdvertismentsQuery();

            if (m.Success)
            {
                query.CountryName = m.Groups["city_country"].Value;
                query.CityOrAreaName = m.Groups["city_country"].Value;
                query.PriceFrom = Convert.ToDecimal(1);
                query.PriceTo = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups["price"].Value);
            }
            else
                return null;

            return query;
```

my search string is "Agadir ca. 600 eur" but "ca." is not "bis" or "zu" and regex is also true. What is wrong with regex? I want that regex is true only if is word "bis" or "zu".

I think this is worng

```
?(bis|zu)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the question mark in `(bis|zu)?`. As it is right now, the `.+` of `<city_country>` matches up to the prices and includes `ca.`.

In fact, you might want to change the whole `?(bis|zu)?` part to `( bis| zu)`.

Comment: what is the difference from ( bis| zu) to ( bis| zu)+. Is the same?

Comment: `( bis| zu)+` Will match any sequence of 1 or more ` bis` or ` zu`. Something like `bis bis bis bis zu bis zu zu bis` would match. EDIT: Ah but you seem to remove the spaces from the string afterwards so you could get rid of all the spaces in the regex as well.

Comment: I meant the `.+` in `(?<city_country>.+)` was the part that matched `ca.` because it matches one or more of any character.

Comment: `(?<city_country>.+)` matches `"Agadir ca. `. `(cca|ca.|ungefähr)` matches the 2nd `ca.` and `(?<price>[\d.,]+) (eur)?` matches `600 eur`.

Answer (score 3):

`Agadir ca.` becomes your `city_country` and `(bis|zu)?`part is skipped as you've marked it as not required with `?`.

Comment: Also because he marked the space between city_country and (bis|zu)? as optional.  Removing that optional space there would also cause the match to fail.

Comment: It's hard to say, his call to `RemoveSpacesFromString` leads you to think that the string will never have spaces no matter what.  But that's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's because you made bis and zu optional. Try changing `(bis|zu)?` to `(bis|zu)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<city_country>.+) ?(bis|zu)? (?<price>[\d.,]+) eur
                    ^        ^
                    1        2
```

1. The first `?` belongs to the space before
2. The second `?` belongs to the `(bis|zu)`

The `?` in these two cases makes the expression before optional